# Bad Request (400) and 502 error: Nginx, gunicorn, django

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my site using nginx, gunicorn, and django.

When I run gunicorn and load the page at first I was getting a 502 Bad gateway error then I switch the server name to the IP address of my server and now I get a Bad Request 400 error or the domain is unable to be found.

I've been following these steps from [Test Driven Development](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch09.html#_trying_it_out).

I realized last night that I was using my staging server to update my live domain instead of a staging domain. So I created a staging domain as a subdomain of the live domain and created a separate directory for it, then git pulled down the work I had done previously, but it's not working.

My nginx conf file:

```
 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name my-server-ip-address;

     location / {
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/mysitename.socket;
     }

      location /static {
         autoindex on;
         root /home/cmac/sites/mysitename/;
     }

 }
```

Nginx Error log:

> 2015/04/11 18:59:16 [error] 18650#0: *494 connect() to
>   unix:/tmp/mysitename.socket failed (111: Connection refused) while
>   connecting to upstream

My settings.py:

```
 DEBUG = False

 TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

 ALLOWED_HOSTS = [mysitename]
```

When I run gunicorn:

```
 [2015-04-11 20:40:39 +0000] [4174] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
 [2015-04-11 20:40:39 +0000] [4174] [INFO] Listening at:      http://127.0.0.1:8000 (4174)
 [2015-04-11 20:40:39 +0000] [4174] [INFO] Using worker: sync
 [2015-04-11 20:40:39 +0000] [4177] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4177
```

Things were working before I decided to switch domains.

Edit whole nginx.conf file

```
user  cmac;
worker_processes  1;


error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include       /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysitename;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;

        #keepalive_timeout  0;
        keepalive_timeout  65;

        #gzip  on;

        # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
        # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
        # for more information.
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

        index   index.html index.htm;

        server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;
            root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

            #charset koi8-r;

            #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

location / {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;
    #    root         html;


 #    location / {
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443;
#    server_name  localhost;
#    root         html;

#    ssl                  on;
#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

#    location / {
#    }
#}
```

The include file (from **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysitename**):

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1;
    server_name my-server-ip-address;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/mysitename.socket;

    }

     location /static {
        autoindex on;
        root /home/cmac/sites/mysitename/;
    }

}
~                                                                                                                               
~
```

Comment: Try changing `unix://...` to your localhost and port like `127.0.0.1:8000` where your gunicorn serves to and see how it goes

Comment: @Anzel still getting Bad Request 400 and nothing in the nginx log

Comment: are you sure you have your gunicorn and django running properly?

Comment: @Anzel I think I do. I'm fairly new to this. When I run unicorn I get:  [2015-04-11 20:40:39 +0000] [4174] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-04-11 20:40:39 +0000] [4174] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (4174)
[2015-04-11 20:40:39 +0000] [4174] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-04-11 20:40:39 +0000] [4177] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4177

Comment: check the server_name settings... are you sure you have changed all others to the same like `www.example.com` but not `staging.example.com`?

Comment: Also, seemed like you're missing **X-Forwarded-For header**, add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`
 right above your `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: @Anzel could you elaborate on that? Changed what others?

Comment: like in your django settings: `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, anywhere you might have  the `server_name` in your nginx.conf etc. You said it was running before you changed the domain from staging wasn't it? so chance will be the domain isn't matched. Also check your dir/files permissions (although unlikely)

Comment: @Anzel I'm trying to load the site onto the staging domain since I was using the live domain previously. In my cpanel, I pointed the domain of the staging server to the subdomain address. It seems even when I don't do: "python3 manage.py run server" or use gunicorn the site still just says bad request. Maybe there is something wrong with the staging server? My ALLOWED_HOSTS list only has the staging site domain.

Comment: @Anzel Additionally, I just repointed the domain of my staging server to my live domain and the site loads without any problems.

Comment: then this is something wrong with your subdomain setup, are you sure your DNS, CNAME are setup properly?

Comment: @Anzel I think so. What's weird (to me) is that I don't understand how my live domain is running from my staging server because i'm not actively running the staging server. I did previously create a .conf file in my /etc/init directory so the server loads automatically on start. Maybe I need to reboot the server to get it working for the staging domain, because I renamed the .conf file to fit the staging domain name.

Comment: Why your staging domain is working on your live one, as a guess, is because you have a wildcard domain matching like `*.example.com` and so the staging will point to live domain.

Comment: I do have the staging server currently directly pointed to the staging server to see if it was a problem with the subdomain name (which now is loading with an Index header). To my understanding, I thought you had to run something like python3 manage.py runsever or gunicorn in order for it to display the contents from the server.

Comment: Yes of course you need `runserver` or `gunicorn` etc. to serve content. The point is, because you're behind a proxy server (nginx), outside world will only see the content your nginx serves (proxy_pass from gunicorn). I assume your gunicorn is running fine, then it leads to nginx whether it serves the content to the *RIGHT* domain, and its relevant configs

Comment: @Anzel Okay, but it's unclear to me where to go from here.

Comment: @Anzel I changed my nginx.conf file to listen from 127.0.0.1:8000. That solves the 400 and 502 errors but now i'm only getting the welcome nginx page instead of my html files on the server.

Comment: that's nginx page is the default page... however it means that there are configs incorrectly set somewhere in your `nginx.conf`, which isn't pointing to the correct server_name. Have you set up any `upstream` in nginx? you need to show the whole conf file.

Comment: @Anzel I included the whole nginx.conf file to the OP

Comment: In `mysitename` you need to listen on `80`, and server name as your `staging.example.com`, also do not use `unix sock` at the moment, put `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in `proxy_pass`. Try also comment out the server block in your  `nginx.conf`.

Comment: Also, are you sure user `cmac` has permissions under your directory/files? normally it runs on `www-data`.

Comment: @Anzel That did it! I guess there was a conflict between the server defined in the nginx.conf file and mysitename (from include)? Thank you. Is there a way to give rep points from the comments?

Comment: I have copy and pasted my last comment with a little explanation so you can accept it. Glad it helps finally, I should have asked you for the whole conf in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `mysitename` you need to listen on port `80`, and `server_name` as your your staging domain like `staging.example.com`, also do not use unix sock at the moment, put `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in `proxy_pass` as where your **gunicorn** serves. Try also comment out the server block in your `nginx.conf`, it has conflicts with your `mysitename`.

Also, are you sure user `cmac` has permissions under your directory/files? normally it runs on `www-data`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @drakoen, you can try and replace the tcp/ip with sockets and see if it works. I asked you to replace this to ensure 1 less mistake. Generally speaking sockets run faster than tcp/ip but not as scalable. I think it doesn't matter much in your use case and tcp/ip is more direct, too :)